# SplitView not layer-backed, but trying to use overlay sidebars

Tags: swift, macos, xcode7, uisplitviewcontroller

This is my first time working with Cocoa, and I've added an NSSplitViewController as the content view of my NSWindowController. I added two side bars to the NSSplitViewController, but I keep getting the following *runtime* warning, and I can't seem to find anything about what is causing this:

```
WARNING: The SplitView is not layer-backed, but trying to use overlay sidebars..
implicitly layer-backing for now. Please file a radar against this app if you see
this.
```

**EDIT:**

Everything is in Storyboards at this point. The NSSplitViewController has three sections, a left sidebar, and main content area, and a right sidebar (think Xcode or Pages). In both sidebars I have a single label (just for testing). Also, this is a *runtime* warning.

Any insight on this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Where is that error appearing? In Xcode, or as a runtime error? Also, how did you add the sidebars to the split view?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just hit the same problem.
Since you are using a sidebar, and sidebars are translucent now, the underlying view needs to be layer backed. To achieve that set the split view to have a core animation layer in the View Effects Inspector:

[image: Setting Layer Backed Property]

Make sure that all other views in your splitview are also marked as layer-backed. I got redraw problems when I forgot that.

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works for now, but it seems a bit odd to turn on simple features like this in code. Is there a way to do this in IB?

Comment: There is no need to set this in code. The visual glitches I experienced before were due to the fact that the _other_ view in the splitview was not marked as layer-backed. (And the code solution actually had the same problem, I just didn't test thoroughly enough.) I edited my answer accordingly. Simply set the property as shown in the link above and make sure all other views involved are marked as layer-backed as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer harmless. The warning disappeared. However I couldn't get rid of the redraw problems. Even if I added an core animation layer in Interface Builder to every view I have. I ended up doing the following in my NSWindowController:         `self.contentViewController!.view.wantsLayer = true`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this recently developing on macOS 11 with Xcode 12.4. It was not enough to check the box in Interface Builder. To eliminate the warning, I had to explicitly set wantsLayer to true in `awakeFromNib`:

```
// Assume splitViewController is an NSSplitViewController stored in an iVar
splitViewController.splitView.wantsLayer = true
```

That finally got rid of the warning.